# Atualização de data no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Eu gostaria de alterar o valor do campo de data no momento de uma edição de dados. Consigo trazer todos os valores, menos os de data.

Estou usando o **Form::** do *Laravel*:

```
{!! Form::label('dtemissao','Data de Emissão') !!}
{!! Form::input('date','dtemissao',$FinContaspagar[0]["DtEmissao"]->format("d/m/Y"), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}<br />
```

Estou usando o `$FinContaspagar[0]["DtEmissao"]->format("d/m/Y")` para alterar o valor padrão de **dd/mm/aaaa**, porém não tive exito na mudança de valor.

Alguém tem alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o formato: `Y-m-d`, exemplo:

```
<input type="date" value="{{$data->format('Y-m-d')}}">
```

no seu código:

```
{!! Form::label('dtemissao','Data de Emissão') !!}
{!! Form::input('date','dtemissao',$FinContaspagar[0]["DtEmissao"]->format('Y-m-d')) !!}
```

Comment: Deu certo @Virgilio Novic obrigado!